# how to add css class on selected list item

Tags: angular

I have a list group and I want to add a css class when one item is selected using ngClass directive

how to verify is the item is selected?

I only have one option.. this is a sidebar component, and when I pick an option, it has to send it to the parent (I did that with @Output) and also have a css class on selected option...

this is my component.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="selectOption(option)" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="option ? 'activate-class' : 'deactivate-class'">
        {{option.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

component.ts

```
  @Output() optionSelected: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  options = [
    {
        title: "Activate account",
        value: NavigationOptions.ACTIVATE_VENDOR
    },
    {
        title: "Deactivate account",
        value: NavigationOptions.DEACTIVATE_VENDOR
    }
];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  selectOption(option) {
    this.optionSelected.emit(option);
  }
```

Comment: It depends on what selectOption() does, i.e. how you store the selected option(s) in your component. Add a method `isOptionSelected(option)`in your component, and use it in your template.

Comment: Show `selectOption(option)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the selected option in a variable  and show the class name dynamically based on that

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="selectOption(option);selectedOption = option.title" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="selectedOption == option.title ? 'activate-class' : 'deactivate-class'">
        {{option.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppwc54?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: that can be useful when selecting multiple items

Comment: i have updated my question with all my code from my .ts file; I only have one option.. this is a sidebar component, and when I pick an option, it has to send it to the parent (I did that with @Output) and also have a css class on selected option...

Comment: Try the modified answer

Comment: one last question... how can i make one option to be selected by default?

Comment: In the .ts file, set selectedOption = "Activate account"

Answer (score 3):

You could store the selected option in a variable and check for that:

```
public selectedOption;

selectOption(option) {
  this.optionSelected.emit(option);
  this.selectedOption = option;
}
```

and then check in the ngClass for this variable:

```
[ngClass]="option === selectedOption ? 'activate-class' : 'deactivate-class'"
```

or if you only want to set activate-class and don't need deactivate-class:

```
[class.activate-class]="option === selectedOption"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to over-complicate things or bloat your ts file with code.

You can simply have a selectOption in the ts file.

**TS :**

```
selectOption; // If your option is an object, which it is - then consider adding an interface for it here
```

There is also no need to have 'deactivate-class', if the class doesn't exist on it, we can assume it doesn't apply.

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="selectOption = option" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'activate-class' : selectOption === option}">
    {{option.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```